# Unexpected behavior from for loop

Tags: go

I sure hope this is something simple.  When I grab information from within an if statement that is inside of a for loop it is not carried to outside of the for loop.  I can print the information from within the if statement just fine and then lose it afterwards.  Am I missing something? Coming from Python I have never experienced this before.

```
func main() {
    var neededinfo string
    for _, slice := range info_slices {
        // Get information out of slices
        if strings.Contains(slice, "indicator ") {
            neededinfo := string(ExeSH("echo '" + slice + "' | awk '{ print $4 }'"))
            neededinfo = neededinfo[1:len(neededinfo)-2]
            fmt.Println(neededinfo) // Returns my information
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(neededinfo) // Returns nothing
}
```

Comment: why are you initializing `neededinfo` again inside the loop?

Comment: I would remove the colon on the first line after your if statement and then see if that works, because `var` is technically initializing the variable.

Comment: @YasirG. You were spot on, the var was being overwritten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely is the fact that you are overwriting the neededinfo variable

```
func main() {
    var neededinfo []string
    for _, slice := range info_slices {
        // Get information out of slices
        if strings.Contains(slice, "indicator ") {
            response := string(ExeSH("echo '" + slice + "' | awk '{ print $4 }'"))
            neededinfo = append(neededinfo, response[1:len(response)-2]
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(neededinfo) 
}
```